# Is ${\log(x)}^2$ uniformly continuous on $(1, \infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Is $f(x)={\log(x)}^2$ uniformly continuous on $(1,\infty)$?

I have found the above question in an old exam and was wondering how to solve it. Actually, a few friends and I have found 2 different solutions, one showing that the function is uniformly continuous, while the other showing that it isn't, and we can't figure out which one is wrong.

Here is the first one:

Let $\varepsilon = 1$ and $\delta>0$ be given. Let $x = \max\{\frac{\delta}{2},e\} > 1$, and $y = x + \frac{\delta}{2} > 1$. Then we have
$$|x - y| = \left|x - \left(x + \frac{\delta}{2}\right)\right| = \frac{\delta}{2} < \delta$$
and
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(y)| &= \left|{\log(x)}^2 - {\log(y)}^2 \right| \\[0.5em]
&= \left|(\log x + \log y)(\log x - \log y) \right| \\[0.5em]
&\geq |(\log e)(\log x - \log y)| \\[0.5em]
&= |\log x - \log y\:| \\[0.5em]
&= \left| \log \left(x+\frac{\delta}{2}\right) - \log x\right| \\[0.5em]
&= \left| \log \left( 1+ \frac{\delta}{2x} \right)\right| \\[0.5em]
&\geq 1 \\
&= \varepsilon,
\end{align*}
so $f(x)$ is not uniformly continuous.

On the other hand, intuitively $f(x)$ "looks" uniformly continuous. I believe that since $f \in \mathcal{C}^1$ in $(1, \infty)$ and the derivative is bounded, $f(x)$ should also be uniformly continuous, but obviously not both can be true, so I must be missing something.

Comment: How do you get $\left| \log \left( 1+ \frac{\delta}{2x} \right)\right| \ge 1$? Note that $x = \max\{\frac{\delta}{2},e\} \ge e$.

Comment: How do you get $\frac{\delta}{2}\gt \delta$? Is that a typo as well?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, thanks

Comment: @MartinR You are right, we completely missed that!

Comment: Write out the details of the second approach rather than using “intuitively” and “should.”

Comment: @TedShifrin I have explained my thought process using the fact that $f$ is continuously differentiatable. We haven't had this in the course, so I am not sure about it, but I haven't managed to find a proof using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$.

Comment: Your "thought process" was perfect. $f$ is $\frac2e$-Lipschitz-continuous by the [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), which you certainly "had in the course".

Comment: @AnneBauval We actually did not! This exam is from a few years ago when apparently was in the coursework for the semester, as there is another question on the exam specifically mentioning it, but we obviously didn't make the connection to this question beforehand because we had no idea it existed.

Comment: Different (but somewhat equivalent) approach: $f(x) - f(y) = \int^x_y f'(s)~\mathrm{d}s$. Did you see that in class?

Comment: @HyperbolicPDEfriend No, we didn't cover differentiation or integration at all yet.

Comment: Did you get a series representation for log?

Comment: No, as far as I know we simply defined it as being the inverse of $\exp$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f : [a,\infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ has bounded (not necessarily continuous) derivative on its domain, then it is uniformly continuous. Indeed, the mean value theorem tells you that for any $x < y$ you have that $$|f(x)-f(y)| = |f'(\xi)(x-y)| \leqslant M |x-y|$$ for some absolute constant depending on $f'$.  In other words, your function is Lipschitz continuous, which is a strong form of uniform continuity.

Comment: Nitpicking: A bounded derivative is sufficient to get uniform continuity, the derivative need not be continuous.

Comment: @MartinR Sure. I was expecting the comment. ;)

Comment: Does the fact that $f$ is not defined on a closed interval change anything? In this case I can see it work, but surely there must be a reason that it isn't defined in a more general case.

Answer (score 2):

You already pointed it out. $f'$ is bounded on $(1, \infty)$, whence $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \leq \sup_{\xi \in (1, \infty)}\lvert f'(\xi) \rvert \lvert x -y \rvert$ for all $x, y \in (1, \infty)$. This is uniform continuity (Lipschitz continuity even).

Concerning your first argument: The second line already is wrong. There is no way that $\tfrac{\delta}{2} >\delta$.
Moreover, it is logically flawed. To "disprove" uniform continuity, you need to show that there is $\varepsilon >0$ such that for every $\delta> 0$ there is a pair $x_\delta, y_\delta \in (1, \infty)$ such that $\lvert x_\delta - y_\delta \rvert < \delta$ and $\lvert f(x_\delta) - f(y_\delta)\rvert \geq  \varepsilon$.
The second line really blurs whether you are attempting to show this.

And as Martin R. correctly points out in the comments: For the proof to work, $\delta$ has to be allowed to become arbitrarily small. But then $\left \lvert \log\left( 1+ \tfrac{\delta}{2x} \right) \right \rvert$ approaches $0$.